# MKV file has too many frames

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to do some video editing with blender (sequence editor). I have imported a .mkv file of 91 minutes and it shows in blender as 4.4 million frames (which is obviously not accurate). It was recorded at 30 frames per second.
I can not set the end frame to the end of the video, the highest blender will apparently go is 1048574. As such I can't even cut out a half hour video because there doesn't seem to be a way to cut past the end frame.
Is there a setting that allows me to set the end frame higher than 1 Million ?

edit: ffprobe output:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 1k fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

edit2: output from ffmpeg command from dr Sybren's answer
input:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 1k fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

output:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 1k fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
```

Comment: Since MKV can contain pretty much all the video codecs on the planet, it's not enough to know the container format. What does `ffprobe yourfile.mkv` say?

Comment: Edited with ffprobe output. It's recorded by OBS, set to 30 fps.

Answer (score 1):

Your source file has inconsistent frame rates in the container and the video stream (see this [explanation of tbc, tbn, and tbr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489/meaning-of-ffmpeg-output-tbc-tbn-tbr#3199582)), so that may throw Blender off. Try running your video file through ffmpeg without re-encoding the streams, and set the frame rate explicitly:

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -r 30 newfile.mkv
```

Comment: No difference in framerate with the new file. Posted output of ffmpeg command in the question

Comment: maybe Blender can't handle yuv420p(progressive). Changing that will require re-encoding your file, though:  `ffmpeg -i yourfile.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -r 30 newfile.mkv`

(you can add `-t 30` to it to test on the first 30 seconds only).